# I have a question about resource alocation to avoid dead lock

Tags: operating-systems, deadlocks, resource-allocation

In the code below, three processes are competing for six resources labeled A to F.How can I modify the get request in each procedure in this graph to avoid dead lock You  cannot  move  requests  across  procedures,  only  change  the  order
inside each procedure.

[image: GRAPH]

Comment: You should edit your answer to show us what you think about this problem, and how you tried to resolve it.

Comment: Take the proof of correctness as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The main resources to be focused here are the common ones : $B$ , $C$ and $D$. To prevent deadlock from ever occurring you should focus on breaking $circular  wait$, which is one of the 4 necessary conditions for deadlock.

For that lets make the common resources request as early as possible: Consider this:

$P_{o}()$  $\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $ $P_{1}()$  $\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $ $P_{2}()$

$get(B)$   $\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $ $get(B)$ $\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $ $get(C)$

$get(C)$   $\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $ $get(D)$ $\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $ $get(D)$

$get(A)$   $\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $ $get(E)$ $\ $$\ $$\ $$\ $ $get(F)$

The proof that the above sequence never leads to deadlock is easy and can be got by considering the **different orders in which common resources are acquired**.